# Specify a pattern for all controllers and methods in spring framework 5

Tags: java, spring

I'm working on upgrading an Spring Framework 4-based application to Spring Framework 5, and one of the differences between them is that `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` has been removed(deprecated since spring framework 4.3).

An example of its behavior:

```java
@Controller
// thanks to ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping, this next annotation is unnecessary
// @RequestMapping("example") 
public class ExampleController {
    
    // this is automatically bound to POST /example/someMethod
    // even though I didn't set any "path"
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void someMethod() {
    }
```

Is there any way to mimick this behavior on spring framework 5? Upgrading over 300 controllers to the same behavior using `@RequestMapping` and `path` is a very daunting task, and we're fine with `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping`'s behavior for now.

Comment: Why not use aop and the @annotation and run it for all classes annotated with @Controller?

Answer (score -2):

You can update context path in your configuration:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /example
```